Adjusting Equation Size in Beamer Presentations to fit the slide
Question:
I'm working on a Beamer presentation and aim to display equations that utilize the maximum available space on each slide. I've experimented with two approaches, but each yields different results.
Approach 1: Using \resizebox

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Equation with \texttt{\textbackslash resizebox}}
    \resizebox{.9\textwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle E = mc^2$}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

In this method, the equation is scaled to 90% of the text width, maintaining its aspect ratio. This effectively enlarges the equation, making it more prominent on the slide.
Approach 2: Using adjustbox with max width and max height

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Equation with \texttt{\textbackslash adjustbox}}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth, max height=0.8\textheight, center}
        $\displaystyle E = mc^2$
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Here, adjustbox is used to constrain the equation within the specified maximum width and height, centering it on the slide. However, this approach doesn't seem to enlarge the equation as much as the first method.
Objective:
I want the equation to occupy the maximum possible space on the slide, both in width and height, without distortion. The first approach achieves this for wider equations, but for taller equations, it may not utilize the available vertical space effectively. The second approach doesn't seem to scale the equation as desired.
Example of a Taller Equation with adjustbox :

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Taller Equation Example}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth, max height=0.8\textheight, center}
        $\displaystyle
        \begin{cases}
            \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{X}-\mu] = 0 \\
            \mathrm{V}(\mathrm{X}) = 1 \\
            \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 = 0 \\
            \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^4 = 3
        \end{cases}
        $
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

In this example, the system of equations is taller than it is wide. Using \resizebox with a fixed width may not effectively utilize the vertical space, leading to suboptimal scaling.

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Equation with \texttt{\textbackslash resizebox}}
    \resizebox{.9\textwidth}{!}{        
    $\displaystyle
        \begin{cases}
            \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{X}-\mu] = 0 \\
            \mathrm{V}(\mathrm{X}) = 1 \\
            \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 = 0 \\
            \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^4 = 3
        \end{cases}
        $}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Question:
How can I adjust the equation's size so that it maximizes the use of both width and height on the slide, especially when using [aspectratio=169]? Is there a method to dynamically scale the equation to fit optimally within the slide's dimensions?
Edit 1 following comments
I tried to play with the calc package but not much success so far...

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\eqwidth}
\newlength{\eqheight}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{attempt to dynamically scale equation}

    \setlength{\eqwidth}{\textwidth}
    \setlength{\eqheight}{0.8\textheight}
    
    % Measure the dimensions of the equation
    \newsavebox{\eqbox}
    \sbox{\eqbox}{$\displaystyle
        \begin{cases}
            \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{X}-\mu] = 0 \\
            \mathrm{V}(\mathrm{X}) = 1 \\
            \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 = 0 \\
            \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^4 = 3
        \end{cases}
    $}
    
    \ifdim\wd\eqbox>\ht\eqbox
        \resizebox{\eqwidth}{!}{\usebox{\eqbox}}
    \else
        \resizebox{!}{\eqheight}{\usebox{\eqbox}}
    \fi

\end{frame}

\end{document}



For the second one you could use \resizebox{!}{0.9\textheight}, i.e., maintain aspect ratio for the width and set the height.

@Marijn The thing is I encapsulate 500 equations a \newcommand and i don't know a priori the dimension of the equation to adapt \resizebox{!}{0.9\textheight} or \resizebox{.9\textwidth}{!}

You could do some tricks like measuring the width and height (with the commands \widthof and \heightof from the calc package) and resize towards the bigger of the two dimensions - but in general changing the font size from slide to slide is a very 'powerpoint-y' thing to do, in LaTeX consistency of the layout is prioritized because it leads to a calmer and more professional appearance.

@Marijn see my edit :)

Just an aside: I don't think that the [aspectratio=169] option has anything to do with your problem. Try removing it and adding one more line to your "tall" equation; you will see the exact same effect.

@nplatis once I try it... you're right !

I edited the question to remove references to aspectratio.

Maybe using expl3 with \box_autosize_to_wd_and_ht_plus_dp:Nnn could be an option. Save equation inside a box and calculate width and height in respect to \textwidth and \textheight (adjust both lengths to your needs).
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment { adjustsize } { +b }
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
    \box_autosize_to_wd_and_ht_plus_dp:Nnn \l_tmpa_box
      { \textwidth } { 0.8\textheight } % <-- set available width and height
    \box_use_drop:N \l_tmpa_box
  }
  {}

% If verbatim material (inline and block) should be typeset
% inside the environment the following is necessary
%
% \NewDocumentEnvironment { adjustsize } {}
%   { \__jet_adjust_begin:w }
%   { \__jet_adjust_end: }
%
% \cs_new_protected:Npn \__jet_adjust_begin:w
%   { \hbox_set:Nw \l_tmpa_box }
% \cs_new_protected:Npn \__jet_adjust_end:
%   {
%     \hbox_set_end:
%     \box_autosize_to_wd_and_ht_plus_dp:Nnn \l_tmpa_box
%       { \textwidth } { 0.8\textheight } % <-- set available width and height
%     \box_use_drop:N \l_tmpa_box
%   }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Equation with \texttt{expl3}}
  \begin{adjustsize}
    $E = mc^2$
  \end{adjustsize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Equation with \texttt{expl3}}
  \begin{adjustsize}
    $\begin{cases}
      \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{X}-\mu] = 0 \\
      \mathrm{V}(\mathrm{X}) = 1 \\
      \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 = 0 \\
      \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^4 = 3
    \end{cases}$
  \end{adjustsize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}




I am still reluctant to using expl3 but you kinda convince me :)

I'd recommend expl3, too, but wouldn't it be simpler to use a +b argument type?

True! Added an alternative with +b argument type.

I don't think you need any more than the standard graphicx just scale up the height+depth, and if that makes the width too large, scale it back to \textwidth.

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\eqn[1]{%
  \sbox0{\resizebox*{!}{.85\textheight}{% room for title
      $\displaystyle#1$}}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\textwidth \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox0}\else\usebox{0}\fi
}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{attempt to dynamically scale equation}

    
  \eqn{a=b}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{attempt to dynamically scale equation}

    
  \eqn{
    \begin{cases}
            \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{X}-\mu] = 0 \\
            \mathrm{V}(\mathrm{X}) = 1 \\
            \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 = 0 \\
            \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^4 = 3
        \end{cases}
    }
 


\end{frame}

\end{document}


Very elegant solution

Note that this solution uses internal macros from memoize. It is, therefore, liable to breakage when memoize is updated. Please do not complain to Sašo if (when) this happens.
Caveat emptor!

This is a modification of samcarter's answer to use memoize, which externalises material far more quickly and efficiently than the external library.
If you install the requisite perl or python libraries, shell escape is unnecessary. I used the default (perl) method below. python is a bit faster, but may require installing python (whereas lots of people have perl, at least if they have TeX Live).
The solution redefines the internal macro \mmz@include@extern. It does this because I couldn't find (or have not yet found) any documented way to alter the command used to include the externalised images ('memo's).
One complication is that we have to change things only after memoize has checked the dimensions of the image match its expectations, because the package will otherwise refuse to include the memoized content.
\RequirePackage{memoize}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731738/ addaswyd o ateb samcarter: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730021/
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newdimen\targettotht
\newdimen\targetwd
\AddToHook {begindocument/end}
{% adjust as desired
  \targettotht=\dimexpr 0.7\textheight
  \targetwd=\dimexpr 0.9\textwidth
}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\jet@tempa
\newdimen\jet@tempb
\def\mmz@include@extern#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
  \mmz@seq=#1\relax
  \setbox\mmz@box=#2{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{%
      \lower\dimexpr #5+#7\relax\hbox{%
        \hskip -#6\relax
        \setbox0=\hbox{%
          \mmz@insertpdfpage{\mmz@extern@path}{1}%
        }%
        \unhbox0
      }%
    }%
    \wd0 \dimexpr\wd0-#8\relax
    \ht0 \dimexpr\ht0-#9\relax
    \dp0 #5\relax
    \box0
  }%
  \mmz@tempfalse
  \mmz@if@roughly@equal{\mmz@tolerance}{#3}{\wd\mmz@box}{%
    \mmz@if@roughly@equal{\mmz@tolerance}{#4}{\ht\mmz@box}{%
      \mmz@temptrue
  }{}}{}%
  \ifmmz@temp
  \else
    \mmz@use@memo@warning{\mmz@extern@path}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
  \fi
  \edef\jet@tempc{\fpeval{\targetwd/#3}}%
  \edef\jet@tempd{\fpeval{\targettotht/#4}}%
  \ifdim\jet@tempc pt>\jet@tempd pt
    \let\jet@tempc\jet@tempd
  \fi
  \wd\mmz@box=#3\relax
  \ht\mmz@box=#4\relax
  \ExpandArgs {ee}\scalebox{\jet@tempc}{\box\mmz@box}%
  \pgfkeysalso{/mmz/record/used extern={\mmz@extern@path}}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\quack}[1]{%
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Equation with \texttt{\textbackslash resizebox}}
  \centering
  \quack{$\displaystyle E = mc^2$}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Equation with \texttt{\textbackslash adjustbox}}
  \quack{$\displaystyle
    \begin{cases}
      \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{X}-\mu] = 0 \\
      \mathrm{V}(\mathrm{X}) = 1 \\
      \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 = 0 \\
      \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^4 = 3
    \end{cases}
  $}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Note that I would use expl3 with or without memoize (most likely with), but I gather you are reluctant ....

there's a question somewhere about using memoize to adjust dimensions .... ; alternatively, scale then memoize?

Some observations:

You need to take into account the totalheight, not only the height of your box. This is why your examples were getting too big for the height of the slide. I cannot explain why this happens, though, someone more knowledgable could enlighten us.
max width/height will not magnify the objects, they are only maximum sizes! You need to use (and think in terms of) min width/height.
Regarding your example which computes which side is bigger, I think we must take into account the aspect ratio of the text as well.

So, taking this as a starting point, here is a solution which I think works:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\eqwidth}
\newlength{\eqheight}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{attempt to dynamically scale equation}

    \setlength{\eqwidth}{\textwidth}
    \setlength{\eqheight}{0.8\textheight}

    % Measure the dimensions of the equation
    \newsavebox{\eqbox}
    \sbox{\eqbox}{$\displaystyle
        % E=mc^2
        \begin{cases}
            \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{X}-\mu] = 0 \\
            \mathrm{V}(\mathrm{X}) = 1 \\
            \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 = 0 \\
            \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^4 = 3
        \end{cases}
    $}

    \ifdim 9\wd\eqbox < 16\dimexpr(\ht\eqbox+\dp\eqbox)
        \adjustbox{min totalheight=\eqheight, center}{%
            \usebox{\eqbox}%
        }%
    \else
        \adjustbox{min width=\eqwidth, center}{%
            \usebox{\eqbox}%
        }%
    \fi

\end{frame}

\end{document}


[Note: I am not a TeX expert, so if the above code can be improved in any way, let me know.]

total height = height + depth

@cfr (a) about total height, now I studied depth a little more and I understand why the "cases" box also has depth. For anyone interested, a nice short explanation of depth is here. (b) about commenting line endings: I added some in the \adjustbox commands; feel free to also edit my answer if more are needed.

This might be annoyingly slow for 500 equations, but just as a proof of concept:
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}


\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code={\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.8\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}}}

\newcommand{\quack}[1]{%
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Equation with \texttt{\textbackslash resizebox}}
    \centering
    \quack{$\displaystyle E = mc^2$}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Equation with \texttt{\textbackslash adjustbox}}
    \quack{$\displaystyle
            \begin{cases}
                \mathbb{E}[\mathrm{X}-\mu] = 0 \\
                \mathrm{V}(\mathrm{X}) = 1 \\
                \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3 = 0 \\
                \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\mathrm{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^4 = 3
            \end{cases}
            $}
\end{frame}

\end{document}




thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I tought about that possibility but it really slows down my (2000) slide compilation. If you don't mind, I'll wait a bit before accepting your answer and see if a solution without eternalization comes up :)

@JeT You should definitely wait - as I said, this is just a proof of concept, nothing I would recommend using :)

@JeT Pardon me for jumping in here guys, but if the slow externalization speed is the reason this isn't working, why not use memoize instead of \tikzexternalize?

@Jasper. Be welcome. oh if it's Saso Zivanovic the author it must be nice. I take a look at the documentation but your answer with memoize can help me dig in the documentation with an example.

@JeT The problem I am running into is I don't know how to automatically resize the memoize pictures, as I don't know how to surround the picture with \includegraphics yet. Let me look a little deeper

was also thinking memoize (@Jasper). it will slightly slow compilation on the first run, but nowhere near as much as externalbecauseexternaluses a separate compilation for ever externalised image, whereasmemoizejust produces an extra page as part of a single run. (also is much nicer thanexternal` :-).

@Jasper I don't think that's a good strategy. to do that, you'd have to subvert the entire inclusion mechanism ....

@cfr I see your point, it would make more sense to operate within the memoize framework

@Jasper on the other hand, redefining internal macros is probably worse ;).
